# Prolog: Checking lengths of lists inside a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm totally new in Prolog and I have problems handling a list that contains other lists. 
I have some lists like this:
`[([5],23),([1],23),([2],43),([4],29),([3],14),([5,1,4,3],47)]`
and I am trying to take the (sub)list with the biggest length and put it first at the list

in this example I want the result to be like this: 
`([5,1,4,3],47),([5],23),([1],23),([2],43),([4],29),([3],14)]`

(don't care whether it will be removed or not from it's starting place).

Thanks to all who will try to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you want to use the built-in sort routine (I'm using SWI-Prolog as example here), then the following would work:

```
calcLen((List,K),(N,List,K)):- length(List,N).
delLen((_,List,K),(List,K)).

sortlen(List,Sorted):- 
  maplist(calcLen,List,List1), 
  sort(0,@>=,List1, List2),
  maplist(delLen,List2,Sorted).
```

The two predicates `calcLen` and `delLen` insert and remove a length calculation at the front of the pairs in the list -- making them triples.  The `maplist` predicate applies `calcLen` (and later `delLen`) to a list.